# Is there some API to check if the lambda was invoked?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Is there some API to check if the lambda was invoked?

My lambda is being invoked by a ddb event. I want to write a test case that can check if the lambda was triggered for a new ddb event.

Is there some API to check if the lambda was triggered?

Comment: Is this AWS lambda? Some language lambda? Please advise.

Comment: Hi, yes. AWS lambda

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no special API to check if a lambda was invoked or not. Instead you can:

- check your function metric [invocation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-metrics.html) , or
- you can use [CloudTrail to track function invocations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/logging-using-cloudtrail.html)